# Rails: Is that safe to store data in "session"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I thought to store the type of the currently logged in user in `session[:user_type]`. The options are: "admin", "end_user", "demo" (may add more user types in the future).

I wonder if it is safe to do that in Rails 3 application.

Can user change somehow the `session[:user_type]` from "demo" to "admin" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of your session store.
By default use cookies as a session store so by default it's not safe it's pretty easy to change the content of a cookie.

So you could either :

- change your session store in
  config/initializers/session_store.rb and use an activerecord store (so it will be store in the db) or a memcache store. There's also plenty of plugins on github letting you use redis, mongodb, ... as sessions stores
- store this information in your db and have a before_filter in your application_controller accessing the cookie to get the current user id and getting the whole user object in a variable @current_user

Comment: One question: If the user id is stored in the cookie, can't user try change it as well ? (after several tries he might guess an admin user id)

Comment: @Misha. You're right, user_id should not be in a cookie, as it can be manipulated. But if you store user_id in session and don't use cookie_store, as Mike's first alternative, you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate (read the article linked to by ThoKra below). Rails signs cookies with a digest, and returns nil for session values if the digest doesn't match, so it's not possible for end users to change the session values even if they're stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 3):

Look in this thread: [Rails sessions current practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices-especially-for-rails-3)