# How to store session id and expiration time to database? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

How to store session id and expiration time to database?  Please give me a suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating sessions in db:

[Rails sessions current practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices-especially-for-rails-3)

Sweeping sessions:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry