# Trying To Set Up Rails To Store Sessions In A Postgresql Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an existing Rails 3.2 app, and I would like to store sessions in a Postgresql database. I found [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices-especially-for-rails-3) on Stackoverflow and followed Diego Pino's directions.

However, when I got to the `rake db:migrate` step, I got the following error:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "sessions_session_id_fkey" cannot be implemented DETAIL:  Key columns "session_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and integer.

Here's the SQL that it's trying to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE "sessions" ("id" serial primary key, 
    "session_id" character varying(255) NOT NULL, 
    "data" text,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, 
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY ("session_id") REFERENCES "sessions" ("id"))
```

And here's the migration that was automatically created:

```
class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration                                    
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.text :date
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sessions, :session_id
    add_index :sessions, :updated_at
  end
end
```

The confusing part to me is that I don't see any foreign key constraint declarations in the migration. So why is the generated sql trying to link together a text field and an integer field?

**UPDATE 1**

Kevin requested the contents of my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Calliope::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_calliope_session'

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
#Calliope::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

I tried re-running the `rake db:migrate` command after uncommenting the `:active_record_store` line at the bottom, but that didn't change the outcome.

I also do **not** have an existing `sessions` table in either my Dev or Test databases.

Comment: Do you have any gems that automatically add foreign keys?

Comment: Please post the contents of `/config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Comment: I am using schema_plus, but I don't know if it automatically adds foreign keys. I'll check that now.

Comment: Andrew was right. The problem was that I am using schema_plus, and that automatically tries to make a field a foreign key if it ends in "_id". Thankfully, schema_plus also makes it possible to override this behavior.

Comment: I know this is just a typo, but you should probably update `t.text :date` in your `AddSessionsTable` migration to `t.text :data`. Just an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the docs for the [schema_plus](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus) library using Andrew's advice above, and here's the root of my problem:

> SchemaPlus adds support for foreign key constraints. In fact, for the common convention that you name a column with suffix _id to indicate that it’s a foreign key, SchemaPlus automatically defines the appropriate constraint.

Thankfully, this behavior can be overridden in your migration by using the `:references => nil` setting. Checkout the [README](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus/blob/master/README.rdoc) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SQL generated, this jumps out:

```
FOREIGN KEY ("session_id") REFERENCES "sessions" ("id"))
```

Your table name is `sessions`, but it's referencing what looks like another table named `sessions`. For some reason it's indicating that the `session_id` column in this table is a foreign key to the `id` column in a table named `sessions`.

So it's clear that it can't make the `session_id` column in your sessions table a foreign key to the `id` column in the same table -- as the error tells you:

```
Key columns "session_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and integer.
```

According to the docs for [ActiveRecord::SessionStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html):

> A session store backed by an Active Record class. A default class is provided, but any object duck-typing to an Active Record Session class with text session_id and data attributes is sufficient.

Here's the link to the page:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SessionStore

Can you post the contents of your `/config/initializers/session_store.rb` file?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I updated my question above with the contents of that file. I already have "sessions" controllers and views, but no models. I created these earlier to help manage sessions. Could those files be contributing to these problems?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for all of the insight, but it ended up being a feature of the schema_plus library that I was using.