# how to set session variable with ajax request on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to set session variable on ajax call on rails. I have following ajax code:

```
         $.ajax({
              url: '/dashboard/set_session',  
              type: 'GET',
               data: {
                  site_id: site_id
              },
              dataType : 'json'
          }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            });
```

And on rails end:

```
    def set_session
      puts params[:site_id]
      session[:site_id] = params[:site_id]
      puts session[:site_id] 
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: 'success'}
      end
    end
```

The first and second puts print same value. That means the session is set. But when I navigate to other pages or reload the page, the session value of site_id is cleared.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631614/unable-to-set-use-session-variables-in-ruby-on-rails-controller) similar thread

Comment: @Abhi That link does not answer my question

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: You can try doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12866262/3491275), or passing the CSRF token in the AJAX request.