# rails 4.0, rake db:sessions:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Rails 3.1 suggests running

```
rails generate session_migration
```

However this generates the exact same migration as

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

but none of the commands are recognized by my setup using rails 4.0

errors are :

> Could not find generator session_migration.

and

> Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:create'

respectively.

I have run:

> gem install 'activerecord-session_store'

How do I make it work so that i can store a shopping cart bigger than 4kb?

Comment: People who find the answer helpful should also upvote the question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The ActiveRecord session store has been extracted out of Rails into it's own gem as part of Rails move towards better modularity. You need to include the gem as shown below in your `Gemfile` to get access to the `rake` task and related functionality.

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
```

- [The gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store)
- [The Rails commit where the change happened](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0ffe19056c8e8b2f9ae9d487b896cad2ce9387ad)
- [A bit of an explanation](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013)

See the README of the gem linked above for more instructions, but you still need run the following command after installing the gem

```
rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

and after that you need to modify the *config/initializers/session_store.rb* to look like something like this

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_Application_session'
```

or

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_Application_session'
```

depending on your Rails version.

Comment: I try this  but "Could not find generator active_record:session_migration"

Comment: After updating gemfile, try to "bundle install" in console

Comment: You may need to run "bundle exec rails generate active_record:session_migration"