# cucumber tests Fail with ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow after rails4 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, cucumber

The error looks like below.

And I have already imported all books

```
#features/step_definitions/book_steps.rb:10
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow)
features/reports/reports.feature:11:in `And I have already imported all books'
```

I searched around and decided to use the suggestions made in the following two posts, to switch to db session store.

[Cookie overflow in rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application)
[rails 4.0, rake db:sessions:create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655744/rails-4-0-rake-dbsessionscreate)

However, I still see this error in the cucumber tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to migrate/recreate your test database?

You should check your test and cucumber environments to see if they are not configured differently.