# Sharing devise session between two rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got two apps running on different domains. Those Rails 3.2 applications are using exactly the same user database and same authentication gem (Devise).

Is it possible to share session between those two apps? I tried to setup `Application.config.secret_token` into same values, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your apps don't share any other parts of the stack than the database I think that would be a nice place to start. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices-especially-for-rails-3) about how to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks fiskeben, I will check this solution and get back here to accept your answer.